# duplicate column when using backpacks laravel CRUD

Tags: php, laravel

any one tell me why my field is duplicated when using laravel backpacks ? Although follow https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-example but i have bug , thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3MMA.jpg)

Comment: please, show your setup() function from current crud controller

Comment: that is it :   public function setup()
    {
        $this->crud->setModel("App\Models\Tag");
          $this->crud->setRoute("admin/tag");
          $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('tag', 'tags');

          $this->crud->setColumns(['name']);
          $this->crud->addField([
   'name' => 'name',
   'label' => "Tag name"
   ]);

        $this->crud->setFromDb();

Comment: i'm so sorry, this is the first time i use stackoverflow to ask, so don't know how to make the comment look well !

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on writing a good question and edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the "name" column two times:

```
1 - `$this->crud->setColumns(['name']);`

2 - '$this->crud->setFromDb();'
```

Info from [laravel/backpack](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-full-api) documentation:

```
$this->crud->setFromDb();  // automatically set fields and columns from your database columns  TODO: rephrase
```

Remove **$this->crud->setFromDb();** and you get one "name" column

Hope it help you:)

Comment: thank you so much, i had been sitting half a day, but  i worked, thank you again